# Get results for one day back in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get results  from 1 day back, for example if i have a job that runs today at 1:00:00 am the 22/05/2018 i want it to get back the results for the 21/05/2018 00:00:00 am to 21/05/2018 23:59:59 pm.

i tried the follwing

```
select *
from table
where CreatedDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day, -0, GETDATE()) // it brings back everything from yesterday and today
```

example of how my created date time is stored in the db `2018-05-21 16:39:09.4830000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bewteen` operator filters the dates based on `>=` and `<=`

You need :

```
select *
from table
where CreatedDateTime >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND 
      CreatedDateTime <  GETDATE();
```

I suspect you would need `cast(... as date)` if so, the you can directly express this as

```
select *
from table
where cast(CreatedDateTime as date) = cast(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as date);
```

Here is a good *[BLOG](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)* on filtering date range in query.

Comment: Thanks ,i tried the first option first it returned todays records as well,so i tried your second option and then that worked.I also tried the following 'CreatedDateTime >=dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()-1), 0) + '00:00:00:000' and CreatedDateTime<=dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()-1), 0) + '23:59:59:000'' which worked as well,but your option looks better,i just wanted to know is that with your option no matter what time of day i run the query it will only give me the results between 00:00 and 23:59?

Comment: @KatePillay. . . For second query time is no matter.

Comment: so it will just look for yesterdays date only ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CreatedDateTime BETWEEN GETDATE() -1 AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: It's usually as simple as this. GETDATE() - 1 is exactly 1 day ago.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yeah, I probably should have added my comment in the original answer.